# C++ Adding strings to list to a txt file by command line app

Tags: c++, list, fstream

Ok guys, sorry for this stupid questions, but I', starting programing at C++

A have to save "list of strings " to txt file.

I do know how to open a file

Ive made something like that and its working.

```
void open_file()
{
    string list_cont;
    fstream newlist;
    newlist.open("lista.txt", ios::in);
    while (newlist.good())
    {
        getline(newlist, list_cont);
        cout << list_cont << endl;
    }
    newlist.close();
}
```

beside it, practicing my programing I made something like that

```
struct list{
        przedmiot *first;
        void add_przedmiot(string name, string quantity);
        void delete_przedmiot(int nr);
        void show_list();
        list();
    };
    list::list(){
        first = 0;
    };

    void list::show_list()
    {
        przedmiot *temp = first;
            while (temp)
            {
                cout << "przedmiot: " << temp->name<<endl<< "ilosc: " << temp->quantity <<endl;
            temp = temp->next;
            }

    }




    void list::add_przedmiot(string name, string quantity)
            {
                przedmiot *nowy = new przedmiot;
                nowy->name = name;
                nowy->quantity = quantity;
                if (first == 0)
                {
                    first = nowy;
                }
                else{
                    przedmiot *temp = first;

                    while (temp->next)
                    {
                        temp = temp->next;
                    }
                    temp->next = nowy;
                    nowy->next = 0;
                };

            };
```

But the problem is, i dont know how to "merge" this into one which will be working

Any help guys ?

Comment: User should be able to add strings to list by command line, than list should save to a txt file

Comment: In `add()` there are two string arguments. Which one does the user provide?

Comment: Both, name and quantity like " Carrots" "24kg"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing the user writes every line as "*name* *quantity*", then the following code should do the job:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    using namespace std;
    string input, name, quantity;
    list myList;
    ofstream file;
    file.open("lista.txt");
    while( getline (cin, input) ) { //reading one line from standard input
        istringstream ss(input); // converting to convenient format
        getline(ss, name, ' '); //extract first field (until space)
        getline(ss, quantity); // extract second field (until end of line)
        myList.add_przedmiot( name,  quantity);
        file << name << quantity << endl; // write to file
    }
    file.close()
}
```

Note I used the `istringstream` class, which transforms a string into a stream and is easier to parse.
Moreover, the default delimiter of `getline()` is `\n`, so the second ocurrence of this function inside the loop takes the second field.

You should also check the validity of the input. Moreover, if there are some spaces **inside** the fields, you should define an appropriate delimiter (comma, semicolon), and change it in the first `getline()`.

Comment: `using std;` should be `using namespace std;`

Comment: error C2079: 'ss' uses undefined class 'std::basic_istringstream<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'int

Comment: @BartekKordalski you need to include the relevant includes; `#include <sstream>` etc

Comment: OK that helped,

But now :
error C2784: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::string'

at name >> quanitity >>endl>>file;

Comment: I am a bit tired. The last line in the loop was written in the wrong order, look at the corrected code. And I corrected some other typos.